# Error with __Call on magento

Tags: php, magento, magic-methods

I can't figure this out,

I have a method on my class like:

```
public function __call($closure, $args){
     return call_user_func_array($this->{$closure}->bindTo($this),$args);
}
```

This works on my local server on magento, but when I try to use it on my server
it returns me the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Closure::bindTo() in

I tried adding var_dump to the variables, all have the correct values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Closure::bindTo` exists in PHP 5.4 or newer only. Check your PHP  version.

http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php

Comment: Thanks a lot, we fought a lot with this, apparently the hosting which is an expert hosting for magento has still php 5.3 available on the shared hostings